# Get to Mega Zone in first 30 seconds of a round?

Tags: super-mamc

In Super Monsters Ate My Condo, level 45 (Executive), the 3rd challenge is to reach Mega Zone in the first 30 seconds of a round. I've done this before, the last time I went through all of the levels, and I remember it taking a while before getting the challenge.

What boosts are best, if any, to achieve this goal? What about good strategy for getting to Mega Zone fast?

Answer (score 1):

Three boosts. Starting cat, starting dog,  and double start. Literally, in like five seconds I had got four or five megazones in a row.